# How to pass a variable from controller to eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new attribute (duration) in my model, the main purpose of creating this attribute is to calculate slots according to a specific time duration. though I can set this attribute with the instance of the model that i am creating in controller but when I am fetching multiple rows it is not working,
I would be very thankful for your suggestions about getting a solution for this problem.

Here is my code.

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $counselor = $this->myCounselor($request);
    $counselor_id = $counselor !== null? $counselor->counselorid: null; 
    $date = $request->input('date');

    $availabilities = Availability::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->when($counselor_id, function ($query, $counselor_id) {
            return $query->where('counselor_id', $counselor_id);
        })
        ->when($date, function ($query, $date) {
            return $query->whereDate('date', $date);
        })
        ->where(function($query) {
            return $query->where('date' , '!=', null)
                         ->whereDate('date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));
        })
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->get();

        // $availabilities->duration = 20;

        return response()->json($availabilities);

        // return view('schedule');
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Availability extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, CalculateSlots;

    protected $attributes = ['available_slots', 'duration' => 20];
    protected $appends = ['available_slots'];

    public function getAvailableSlotsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getSlots($this->duration); // I am trying to set this duration attribute's value in my controller.
    }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is your problem? Why not use the duration as an argument to that method? Also, please rethink your architecture: gathering data in such complex ways should better be done in a specific service, such that you can write a test for it

Comment: I am trying to get advantages of Laravel relationships, I could do it by creating a simple method but that would take much time to calculate all the available slots, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $a = new Availability ();
    return $a->getAvailableSlotsAttribute();
}
```

Or use `scope` before your method name in your `model`, like:

```
public function scopegetAvailableSlotsAttribute(){

}
```

In controller you can get it like:

```
Availability::getAvailableSlotsAttribute
```

Comment: Looks good, But keeping each row in a loop would not be a good idea, isn't it?

Comment: A Scope function  is usually used to filter something in generated query, It's not changing any attribute value.